# Validating date by using DateTimePicke in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to validate by selecting only today date from datetimepicker. I used this code. It doesn't work.

```
If DateTimePickerIssue.Value < Date.Today Then
        MessageBox.Show("Date cannot be before today.")
        e.Cancel = True
    ElseIf DateTimePickerIssue.Value > Date.Today Then
        MessageBox.Show("Date cannot be after today.")
    ElseIf DateTimePickerIssue.Value = Date.Today Then
        MessageBox.Show("Date correct today.")
    End If
```

Comment: You need to use DateTimePickerIssue.Value.Date .

Comment: It is very very easy to debug issues like this for yourself.